# I want to create some very specific heatmaps. Can it be done?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, heatmap

First of all, I'd like to explain what I want to achieve.

Imagine that I own a leaflet drop business. I cover a city, which is divided into 10 sections.
I want to leaflet-drop those 10 sections systematically, and have a heatmap that shows when they were last done (ie, if an area was done just last week, it would show up as green, but if it was done 6 months ago, it would be red.)

However, occasionally, I would do additional leaflet drops within the area, that I wouldn't want to be included in the data above - these would then show up on the heatmap in, say, blue.

I've been looking at OpenLayers, and it seems like it can do what I want - but I'm not really that technical, so need advice. OpenLayers has the ability to select specific areas with a polygon tool, which is exactly what I need - but how can I input this data, which will change frequently?

I currently monitor coverage of the territories with an Excel spreadsheet, but would like this heatmap system in addition to that.

So - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Heck, for a tool for you to use yourself, you could use a drawing package like Inkscape.  Scan a map of the area, paste that in, draw polygons for the areas you care about, and then every time you do a drop, change the colour of the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers is generally used by software developers to aggregate geospatial/map data from various sources into web applications used by many users.  OpenLayers can do what you want but not without writing a fair amount of JavaScript code.  You might be looking more for a tool like ESRI's ArcCatalog, although it is probably too powerful for your needs.

I did a quick google search of "best map drawing tools" and found [SmartDraw](http://www.smartdraw.com/specials/map-drawing.htm), for example.  I have no affiliation with SmartDraw, nor do I know if it's any good, but it seems like this type of software would be more suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried SmartDraw, but it isn't suited to my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For what you say would be more useful a desktop tool as e.g. http://www.qgis.org/ (is open source and free)

Comment: I'm currently trying qgis - it seems pretty complex, but I'll do some research on it.